# Changing text color for specific string in JLabel (not the entire JLabel text)

Tags: java, swing

The essence of my problem is this: I'm creating a simple game, an RPG. In it, one can view their skills and their respective levels. Because they can have modifiers, in one JLabel, it displays the name of the skill, its base level and its effective level. I want to be able to change the color of ONLY the portion that displays the effective level, so that it would look something to the effect of "Skill: 20(*red*15). If this is at all possible I'd love to know how to. Otherwise, what would you recommend as the next best thing to this? I'd presume just creating a second JLabel, changing its foregroundcolor and placing it next to the first JLabel?

Comment: You can't do that with a JLabel. You will either have to subclass JLabel and write you own rendering code, or use some type of JEditorPane.

Comment: @FredK Well, technically, you could use `html` styling to achieve the result

Comment: You can style a `JLabel` with `html`, as shown in the duplicate answer, otherwise you will need to use multiple labels to "fake" it

Comment: Thank you. I was unaware that I could use html to that end. I'm unfamiliar with it, so when I saw the question that got this marked as a duplicate, I discounted it because of my lack of knowledge on it. Thank you.